# Undefined method true for (class) mail_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rubygems

I am relatively new in Ruby on Rails programming, and I got this error when trying to use the mail_form gem.
[The error is in the create function as can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWAS7.png)

I think I got all setup the correct way:

My model is like this:

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
      attribute :name,        :validate => :true
      attribute :email,       :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
      attribute :message,     :validate => :true
      attribute :nickname,    :captcha => :true

    def headers
    {
      :subject => "Contact Form",
      :to => "(my email)",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
   end
end
```

I don't know if matters that I'm trying to create a site with only one page, so I have the form to create a new contact in the welcome.html.erb of the pages controller, but I am defining the contact:

```
def welcome
   @admin = Admin.find(1)
   @projects = Project.all.order('created_at DESC')
   @contact = Contact.new
end
```

Also I think that matters, that the create function (that is throwing the error) is in the contacts controller, I don't know if there was ok or it will be better at the same controller as the Contact.new (in the welcome function of pages):

```
def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Thank you for contacting me. I will reply shortly!")
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
    end
end
```

I haven't tested in production yet, only in development maybe this won't happen in production, but I want to know why is this happening to me because I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIoORYeBdhs) of Mackenzie Child and this didn't happen to him, and we have the same code(except for the fact that I am trying to make this in only one view). I don't know if it helps, but this is what I have in my config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

So in development I'm using the gem letter_opener for displaying the messages instead of sending mails, although this affects nothing in the error because the error was showing up way before I installed the gem.

I have searched in many places and in all the questions on stack overflow but I found nothing. If you can help me that would be grate.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I have tested in production with heroku and returns the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
I asked in the gem's github page and I could resolve the issue. It was that in the validation of the attributes on the Contact model I was declaring the `:true` as an object when it has to be only a boolean `true` (without colon before). Good to know for avoiding silly mistakes.